# PHP mail function does not send email to valid account on same domain

Tags: php, dns, phpmailer

I'm using the mail function as follows:

```
mail($emailto, $subject, $body, $headers);
mail('askme@mysite.com', $subject.' / '.$emailto, $body, $headers);
```

The first is intended for the enduser. The second copy is for me for record keeping purposes.

Soometimes the enduser specifies their email address, other times its blank.

1. When an email address is specified, the end user actuallys gets the email without any problem
2. However, no email gets sent to askme@example.com in EITHER case - I've checked the spam folders as well.

In my /mail/new folder I see many FILES created similar to the below. The error is incorrect as askme@mysite.com is a VALID email address (setup using google for domains).

> ```
>   Return-path: <>
>   Envelope-to: myuserid@myhostingprovider.com
>   Delivery-date: Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:37:28 -0400
>   Received: from mailnull by myhostingprovider.com with local (Exim 4.69)
>       id UNIQUEIDZ-7x
>       for myuserid@myhostingprovider.com; Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:37:28 -0400
>   X-Failed-Recipients: askme@mysite.com
>   Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
>   From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@myhostingprovider.com>
>   To: myuserid@myhostingprovider.com
>   Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
>   Message-Id: <EUNIQUEIDZ-7x@myhostingprovider.com>
>   Date: Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:37:28 -0400
>
>   This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
>   A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
>     askme@mysite.com
>       No Such User Here
>
>   ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
>
>   Return-path: <myuserid@myhostingprovider.com>
>   Received: from nobody by myhostingprovider.com with local (Exim 4.69)
>       (envelope-from <myuserid@myhostingprovider.com>)
>       id UNIQUEIDV-6b
>       for askme@mysite.com; Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:37:28 -0400
>   To: askme@mysite.com
>   Subject: mysite.com: SUBJECT / enduser@gmail.com
>   X-PHP-Script: www.mysite.com/mysitescript.php for IPADDRESS
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   From: mysite.com Service <askme@mysite.com>
>   Message-Id: <EUNIQUEIDV-6b@myhostingprovider.com>
>   Date: Mon, 28 Jun 2010 12:37:28 -0400
> ```

Comment: Have you actually verified that the email address is valid?

Comment: Yes, the email address is valid, no issues sending/receiving via regular email client...

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. You should check to see if `$emailto` is blank before actually calling the `mail` function. You don't want PHP to try to send mail to a blank address.
2. Your problem with `askme@mysite.com` not being delivered is probably a result of your local website host (`mysite.com`) trying to deliver mail to what it considers a "local" address - since it's on the same domain, when in reality that email exists out in Google Apps. Your mail server (like postfix or sendmail) should have a setting to disable this "shortcut".

Comment: ............. yes... that second point sounds like it... I'm on a shared server hosting - how/where do i look for this "option"? The provider has given us cpanel access as well (besides a shell account)

Comment: try cPanel -> MX Entry -> Email Routing -> Remote Mail Exchanger.  don't forget to upvote helpful answers and mark one correct :)

Comment: I was racking my brain for over an hour trying to figure this out, worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you send an email to that address using a normal email client (web one like hotmail/gmail or Outlook/Thunderbird)?

If you can't - your email account isn't setup correctly.

If you can - your email account is setup to ignore your domain or something similar (perhaps a spamfilter pretending the user does not exist?).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **sendmail** go to the config file and using **MX records** to point to **Google Apps** like I do, do the following:

```
sudo vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

add this:

```
FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
```

restart send mail

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sendmail restart
```